# Подключение картинки из модульного css файла

Tags: css, reactjs

Здраствуйте, в `react js` хочу подключить картинки. Есть отдельная папка `images`. Картинки там и в папке `components` разделены на папки, где находятся компонент и его модульный css файл (в картинках всё будет видно). Проблема в том, что не могу подключить картинки. Если в css коментировать `background/background-image`, то всё работать будет.

[image: вот путь к файлам и код]

[image: а это эрор]

Comment: попробуй поставить слеш перед src. - /src/..../nameImg,png

Comment: спасибо, проблема решилось вот так ../../images/image.png  но так и не понял как